# Python script not triggering jQuery form reset via ajaxForm

Tags: jquery, python, html, ajax, forms

I've searched with no luck, so please forgive me if this is redundant.  I'm new to Python, and have a simple HTML form that (on submission) clears the form, sends an email via action.py script, and alerts a message (alertify js) on the same form page.  The email gets sent correctly, but the form does not clear and I do not receive the alert message.  The (stripped down) HTML form is:

```
<form id="myForm" method="post" title="Contact Info Request Form"  action="action.py">
    <fieldset>
        <input type="text"  title="field for entering your name" name="name" id="name" maxlength="50" placeholder="Name" />
        <input type="text" title="field for entering your email address" name="email" id="email" maxlength="50" placeholder="Email" />
        <textarea title="field for entering your message" name="message" id="message" rows="5" cols="4" maxlength="1000"placeholder="Message"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" class="submit" name="submit" value="send message" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

my jQuery script is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
    $('#myForm').ajaxForm(function() { 
        $('#myForm').trigger("reset"); 
        alertify.success("Message sent.  Thank you!");
    }); 
});
```

and my action.py script is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import cgi, cgitb 
import sys

SENDMAIL = "/usr/sbin/sendmail" # sendmail location

form = cgi.FieldStorage() 

if form.getvalue('email') is not None:
    FROM = form.getvalue('email')
else:
    FROM = "no-reply@DOMAIN.com"
TO = ["ACTUALMAIL@address.com"]

SUBJECT = "A message from your site!"
NAME = form.getvalue('name')
TEXT = form.getvalue('message')

# Prepare actual message

message = """\
From: %s
To: %s
Subject: %s

Name: %s
Message: %s
""" % (FROM, ", ".join(TO), SUBJECT, NAME, TEXT)

# Send the mail
p = os.popen("%s -t -i" % SENDMAIL, "w")
p.write(message)
p.close()
sys.exit()
```

My permissions are set correctly on the initial form page, as well as the python script (action.py).  I'm going to add some validations later, but I'd like to have this workign for now.  Calling action.py directly works fine from the command line, but I want it to run on the HTML form page.  I initially had an action.php (essentially the same in PHP) that worked perfectly, but I've been attempting to make it work in python.  Thank you for any constructive help you all may be able to offer me!

Answer (score 0):

This is a shot in the dark, but try `return false` after the trigger reset and the alertify success stuff.

Comment: No luck.  I've added return false to the ajaxForm function, but it still is incorrect.  Thanks anyways!